# How many times must I set default application?

Tags: default-applications

So this problem has been annoying me for quite some time. 
Whenever I select a link via Chrome( a YouTube link) a dialog 
pops up asking if I want to view the link in the browser or in 
the YouTube application. I always select the YouTube application and 
then proceed to select it as the default application to launch on 
any YouTube links.

So the problem is that the next time I click another YouTube link
the dialog pops back up for me to select what action to perform. This 
doesn't only happen with YouTube but with other applications...
I tried resetting all the applications to "default" and retried the 
process but it occurs again.

I understand that there are other posts but, those were all for 
older versions of android.

DEVICE 
- Samsung Note 3 (4.4.2)

Thanks in advance for any resolutions
samthewildone

Comment: Can you please confirm what the default application is under the Application settings for their respective apps.

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of Youtube links. So as long as the types differ the intent chooser will popup asking to choose the default. I suggest just keep ticking the "Use as Default" check box and select YouTube Application.